# Incorrect epoch labelling

Tags: python, continuous-signals, eeg

I am processing an EEG signal acquired by showing 10 image of each of 40 classes. I want to label the signals converted to epochs to their corresponding class labels.

The `event_dict` contains data

`[('initial event', 65280), ('initial event', 65533), ('airliner', 65281), ('watch', 65281), ('folding chair', 65281), ('radio telescope', 65281), ('jack-o-lantern', 65281),`

I am plotting the epochs to view the class labelling

`epochs.plot(n_channels=10, events=events, event_id=event_dict_as_dict)`

The epochs are plotted but the label from the second last class label 'Pool table' is used only: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyO0k.jpg)

All initial class labels are ignored.

The epochs are not correctly labelled